# Getting error while using sessionStorage in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session-storage

I am getting the following error while using sessionStorage in angular.js.

> Error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
    at Object.parse (native)
    at new <anonymous> (http://localhost/Gofasto/controller/dashboardController.js:9:17)
    at e (http://localhost/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:39:193)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:39:310)
    at http://localhost/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:80:313
    at q (http://localhost/Gofasto/js/angularuirouter.js:7:14338)
    at A (http://localhost/Gofasto/js/angularuirouter.js:7:14699)
    at n.$broadcast (http://localhost/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:135:317)
    at t.transition.N.then.t.transition.t.transition (http://localhost/Gofasto/js/angularuirouter.js:7:10000)
    at http://localhost/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:118:334
```

My objective is i have a login page whose url is `http://localhost/Gofasto/` and when user will successfully logged in user will redirect to dashboard page which is coming in this `http://localhost/Gofasto/#/dashboard` url.I am using sessionStorage object to store some value at the time of login. when user has logged in the page and redirected into the dashboard page there is no error. Suppose after logged in user unknowingly delete that tab and again open page using the direct url `http://localhost/Gofasto/#/dashboard` in new tab at this time those errors are coming.I am explaining my code below.

> loginController.js:

```
var loginAdmin=angular.module('Channabasavashwara');
loginAdmin.controller('loginController',function($scope,$http,$location,$window){
    $scope.user_name = ''; 
    $scope.user_pass = '';
    $scope.user_login=function(){
    if($scope.user_name==''){
        alert('user name filed should not keep blank');
    }else if($scope.user_pass==''){
        alert('password filed should not keep blank');
    }else{
        var userData={'user_name':$scope.user_name,'user_pass':$scope.user_pass};
        console.log('user',userData);
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "php/Login/login.php",
            data: userData,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).then(function successCallback(response){
            //console.log('response',response.data.user_name);
            alert(response.data['msg']);
            var loginData={'user_name':response.data.user_name,'pass':response.data.password,'user_type':response.data.user_type};
            $window.sessionStorage["loginInfo"]=JSON.stringify(loginData);
            //console.log('session',$window.sessionStorage["loginInfo"]);
            $location.path('dashboard');
        },function errorCallback(response) {
            alert(response.data['msg']);
        });
    }
    }
});
```

> dashboardController.js:

```
var dashboard=angular.module('Channabasavashwara');
dashboard.controller('dashboardController',function($scope,$http,$window,$state){
    console.log('storage',$window.sessionStorage["loginInfo"]);
    //console.log('storage',data.user_type);
    if($window.sessionStorage["loginInfo"]=='undefined'){
        console.log('storage1',$window.sessionStorage["loginInfo"]);
        $state.go('/',{}, { reload: true });
    }else{
        var data=JSON.parse($window.sessionStorage["loginInfo"]);
        $scope.user_type=data.user_type;
    }
     $scope.Logout=function(){
         $window.sessionStorage.removeItem("loginInfo");
     }
})
```

My requirement here is once user has logged in one browser and at any time  wanted to directly get into the dashboard page it can happen but if without login if user wanted to get into  directly to the dashboard page `i.e-http://localhost/Gofasto/#/dashboard` it will not happen,user will again return to the login page for login.Please help me.

Comment: What does `$window.sessionStorage["loginInfo"]` return?

Comment: @OmriAharon : after login it is working fine but once user has logged in and delete that tab same time again user directly opened the dashboardpage in new tab it is returning undefined.

Answer (score 0):

sessionStorage is per-tab.  Opening a new tab gives a fresh, blank sessionStorage.  You want localStorage if you want cross-tab information.